# How to create jad file for cod file for blackberry berry app?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, jad

I built a blackberry app with Phonegap.  Phonegap build website built my app and then sent me back a StandardInstall.zip.  WHen I open it up, I have cod, alx , csl and cso files.  Don't I also need a jad file in order for me to upload the whole app to my webserver for other blackberries to install my app?

If so, how do I create the jad file?  If I don't need the jad file, how do I install the app?  When I go to http://mysite.com/filename.cod, it just downloads the cod.  It doesn't install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, I wasted a whole day on this.  So I ended up finding a random jad file on the internet which i"m posting here:

```
BlackBerryWebWorksSDK.exe*       glww.jpeg
George Website .pdf              jdk-7u3-windows-i586.exe*
Requirements.xls                 phonegap-phonegap-1.5.0-0-gde1960d/
Manifest-Version: 1.0
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 3329401
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-2-1: ____HOVER_ICON_[LOCAL URL FOR YOUR APP ICON],focused
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
RIM-COD-Size: 70020
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0
MIDlet-Name: [NAME OF YOUR APP]
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-Count-2: 1
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-Count-1: 1
RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies: net_rim_cldc,net_rim_bb_web_jse_api,net_rim_xml_org,net_rim_bb_
browser_field2_api,net_rim_os,net_rim_bbapi_phone,net_rim_bbapi_mailv2,net_rim_bbapi_push,ne
t_rim_bbapi_messagelist,net_rim_pdap,net_rim_bbapi_invoke,net_rim_bbapi_browser,net_rim_netw
orkapi,net_rim_bb_browser_field_api,net_rim_xml,net_rim_locationapi
MIDlet-Vendor: Unknown
RIM-COD-URL: [FILENAME.cod]
MIDlet-Description: [NAME OF YOUR APP]
RIM-COD-Module-Name: [NAMEOFYOURAPPWITHNOSPACES]
RIM-COD-Size: 51568
MIDlet-1: [NAME OF YOUR APP],[LOCAL URL FOR YOUR APP ICON],rim:foreground;WIDGET;
RIM-COD-Creation-Time: 1333316339
```

Replace anywhere you see `[CAPS]` with your values.  Everything else I left the same.  I have no idea if what I've done is a sustainable way for deploying cod files.  I also don't know if there are any consequences for not changing any of the other values like creat dates, file sizes, etc...